# Iterate all available tiles in cocos2d using CCTMXTiledMap

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using the `CCTMXTiledMap` class to load maps into the cocos2d game that I'm making. As part of the process, I would like to iterate through the properties of all available tiles in the tile sets associated with the `.tmx` map file -- INCLUDING ones that are not currently placed on a layer. In other words, I want to know max GID for tiles associated with the map.

I want to do something like:

```
for (int i = minGID; i < maxGID + 1; i++) { 
    ... do something with the tiles by calling their GID... 
}
```

How do I determine the minGID and maxGID associated with the `.tmx` file?

Comment: only tiles which have had one or more properties added in tiled will have a properties dictionary. Do you want to enumerate properties or tile gids?

Comment: I want to enumerate the tile GIDs. It's ok if they don't have properties. I'm playing around with the `<tile id="75" terrain="8,8,8,5">` terrain values but would like to only iterate through the tiles one time -- grabbing properties and terrain information.

Comment: Some of the tiles lack properties but have terrain information.

Comment: ok, then your example code is misleading.

Comment: Ok, fixed the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since cocos2d is limited to one tileset per layer, each tile layer actually has a tileset reference:

```
CCTMXLayer* floorLayer = [tilemap layerNamed:@"floortiles"];
CCTMXTilesetInfo* tileset = floorLayer.tileset;
uint32_t firstGID = tileset.firstGID;
```

So far, so good. But what's the max GID? This can be obtained for all tilesets except for the last rather easily. Assuming you have two tile layers with different tilesets, then the second layer's firstGID subtracted by one is the previous layer's maxGID.

For the last layer you can assume that the maxGID is the number of possible tiles in the tileset. However this does not account for tilesets that aren't completely filled with actual tiles. The other option is to iterate over all layers using this tileset and recording the highest GID in use. Again this is flawed because the tile with the highest GID may not actually be placed on the map.

The only definite solution to work around this is to add a dummy layer and add the highest GID to it at 0,0 and then check the tile GID of that position on the dummy layer. That's how you know for sure what the highest GID of a tileset is. Provided there is no human error in the process and you remember to update the tile if you add more tiles to the tileset.

The only other way to accurately infer this information programmatically is scanning the texture and excluding all unused tiles, by checking each tile area and find the first one that's totally transparent or single (specific) color. This will only work if your tileset is filled left to right, top to bottom without any "empty" tiles in between.

From all these options the one I use in [KoboldTouch](http://www.koboldtouch.com) is to simply assume that the tileset with the highest-most firstGID value is entirely filled with tiles, meaning lastGID will be:

```
uint32_t lastGID = firstGID + (texWidth/tileWidth) * (texHeight/tileHeight) - 1;
```

That's good enough for almost all cases.

Comment: Yes! That's what I was getting at. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: I suppose that CCTMXTiledMaps aren't meant to be altered with during runtime. Is there no way of dynamically and deterministically swap a tile for another at run time? I want to be able to have the user choose floors from a HUDMenu :/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int rowSize = self.mapSize.width/TILE_SIZE ;
int colSize = self.mapSize.height/TILE_SIZE ;

for(int i=0; i<rowSize;i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<colSize; j++)
    {
        unsigned int tileGid = [self.meta tileGIDAt:ccp(i,j)];
        [[myMap propertiesforGID:tileGid] doSomethingCool];

        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Right -- but that only captures tiles that are placed on the map. I want to capture all tiles that are available to place on the map.

Comment: this code works, it will just return tile GID 0 for empty tiles but it does iterate over all tiles. Ignore the propertiesForGID part.

Comment: I guess I'm not explaining myself well and I apologize for that. For this use, I'm not interested in the tiles that are actually placed at a map coordinate. I'm interested in all of the tiles in the tileset -- those that would be listed if I were to export the `.tsx` file. This looks like it iterates through all of the map coordinates.